# HiveQL - extract regular expression that matches a pattern at the end of the string

Tags: regex, hiveql

This might be a silly question but I can't seem to overcome this myself -

I have a field with strings, which sometime end with 3 numbers separated by commas, for example

`- 2353535.123213.124
- data.2354234.1324.1314
- data.old-24234.2341.4325`

and sometimes not

`- aaaa.53535
- data.old-3521
- data.AFG34fsaf34`

Whenever the first case occurs, I need to extract the 3-numbers pattern from the end of the string. Meaning:

`- 2353535.123213.124 -> 2353535.123213.124
- data.2354234.1324.1314 -> 2354234.1324.1314
- data.old-24234.2341.4325 -> 24234.2341.4325
- aaaa.53535 -> Do nothing`

Is that possible?
If not through hiveQL (although this is preferable), even a java regular expression extraction would be helpful (to use in a custom UDF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\\d+(?:\\.\\d+){2}$
```

You can use this `java` expression.[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/1)

Comment: Thanks! Although looks great in the demo I fail to use it in Hive: "select regexp_extract('a.b-983475.9900291.556901','\\d+(?:\\.\\d+){2}$');" produces  
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''\\d+(?:\\.\\d+){2}$'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  on object ...

Comment: @KeshetE you probably need ` regexp_extract('a.b-983475.9900291.556901','\\d+(?:\\.\\d+){2}$',0)`